# repeating nth times of a value in a column of a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-filtering

I have a DataFrame with 3532 rows and 20 columns in Python. I am trying to repeat the 5times of each value from the first row of the column of 'Snew' up to the 706th value. If you see the column below, I have 'Snew' column that has 3532 rows but I just want to repeat 5 times each value from the first row to the value of the 706th row, then I will have a new column with a repeated value with 3532 rows.
I would be happy if anyone have any idea. I tried df.repeat also concatenate command in numpy and pandas  but it is not working well

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with `Series` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Snew':range(3532)})

#seems in real data is necessary add next value (707) and filter 3532 values
df['Snew'] = np.repeat(df['Snew'].to_numpy()[:707], 5)[:3532]
print (df.tail())
      Snew
3527   705
3528   705
3529   705
3530   706
3531   706
```

Comment: Morning, Sir @jezrael.   How are you doing these days?